# Properties file existance?

Tags: java, jar, properties

Q-Properties file existance ??

how can i test the existence of property file (test.properties) inside a jar file.this is my code

```
            JarFile jarfile=new JarFile("C:/path to jar file/file.jar");
            InputStream is=jarfile.getInputStream(jarfile.getEntry("test.properties"));
            Properties properties=new Properties();
            properties.load(is);
            if(properties.isEmpty()){ System.out.printn("file not exist");
```

Comment: Do you mean programmatically? What have you tried?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2433/resources-on-classpath#t=201701111734535687024&a=remarks .